# Display pdf in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I'm trying to build a website with angular.js but I'm having some trouble displaying a pdf. What I'm trying to do is get a pdf that is stored as a blob in a mysql database and then display it as one of my partial views which is brought into the main page when the link is clicked. I haven't been able to find anything that explains this very well. 
This is the code for my controller. I also have a small php script that gets the file from the database. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  var about = angular.module('about', []);
    app.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.post('PHP/aboutSearch.php', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
            .success(function(response){
                var file= new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                $scope.content = $SCE.trustedAsResourceURL(fileURL);
            });
   });



<?php

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT doc FROM tbl_docs WHERE id = 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $content = $row['doc'];
    header('content-type: application/pdf');
?>
```

Comment: Checkout PDF.js ( http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ ) - its a library that looks like it could work with Angular quite well and handles all the PDF related functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try [angularjs-pdf](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf) it's a directive using mozillas [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)